# openpyxl: merged_cell_ranges and merged_cells are both empty

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have a newly created xlsx workbook with one sheet. A1:A2 is merged and contains the string 'test'.

Using openpyxl (2.3.0) I can access the sheet and the cell value but `worksheet.merged_cell_ranges` and `worksheet.merged_cells` are both empty:

```py
wb = workbook.worksheets[0] # ReadOnlyWorksheet: <ReadOnlyWorksheet "Sheet1">
wb.cell(row=1, column=1) # 'test'
wb.merged_cell_ranges # list: []
wb.merged_cells # set: set([])
```

The documentation (http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/openpyxl.worksheet.html) and answers to other SO questions indicate that this is not the expected behaviour.

Yes, the cells are definitely merged. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What significance do merged cells have in read-only worksheets?

Comment: I want to iterate over a sequence of merged ranges (eg A1:A3, A4:10, A11:A15) without having to assume that any empty cell is merged with the previous non-empty cell.

Comment: Probably thing worth to mention here: while opening the sheet I had to use `use_iterators=False` in order to get ranges exposed to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `merged_cells` and `merged_cell_ranges` properties are not populated when the workbook has been opened in read-only mode.

Prompted by Charlie Clark's comment, I opened the workbook without the read-only flag and the `merged_cells` and `merged_cell_ranges` properties were correctly populated.

Submitted [bug #540](https://bitbucket.org/openpyxl/openpyxl/issues/540/reading-list-of-merged-cells-impossible-in).

Comment: This isn't an answer.

Comment: It explains why the properties in question were empty and what to do to resolve the problem. If someone else had answered this, I would have accepted it as the answer.