# Reading Merged cells range in Openpyxl Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Is it possible to get the range of merged cells using `worksheet.merged_cells.ranges`, while loading the workbook in read_only mode using `openpyxl.load_workbook(read_only=True)` ?

I have got the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'ReadOnlyWorksheet' object has no attribute 'merged_cells'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect merged cells in excel with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39574991/how-to-detect-merged-cells-in-excel-with-openpyxl)

Comment: @Tomerikoo, I have edited the question with the error.

Comment: @venky__ It works good in normal mode. But I am not able to get the range only when I load it in read_only mode.

Comment: Realted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33412105/openpyxl-merged-cell-ranges-and-merged-cells-are-both-empty

Comment: From going over the source code of `read_only.py` under `worksheet` it doesn't seem like there is anything at all related  to merged cells (the `ReadOnlyWorksheet` is defined there)

Comment: There's sort of no point because the info is right at the bottom of the XML so you still need to parse the whole worksheet which will limit the effectiveness of read-only mode.